# How can I turn a bullet image into a link?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

CSS

```
 .rss {

    margin: 5px 5px 0 5px;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%
    }
.rss li {

    display: inline-block;
    width: 40%;
    margin: 0 2% 0 0 ;
    list-style-type: none;
    background: #fff url("http://Images/Goldnbluebutton.gif") 0 3px no-repeat;
    padding: 0 0 5px 15px;
    display: -moz-inline-box;
}
```

---

HTML

```
  <ul class="rss">
     <li><a href="link goes here" target="_parent">
        <img src="Images/Goldnbluebutton.gif"id="Goldnbluebutton_22">    
         </a><strong>Sue Vercauteren, </strong><em>Director of Children's Ministries</em></li>
```

---

result: (image appears instead of bullet)

### **Sue Vercauteren,** *Director of Children's Ministries*

---

I need to make the bullets to the left of the li items into an image and a link. I know how to code the css to add the image but I can't figure out how to make it a link?

I can make the image appear using CSS but I want my link to work when the image is clicked.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Add the `background-image` to `.rss li a` instead of the `li` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the list as you would normally, including the link tag itself.

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
</ul>
```

Style your bullets and specify that they should be positioned inside the >li> not outside.

```
ul {
    list-style-position: inside;
}
```

Specify a padding for your links (ex.: 20px) and position the links relatively (to the left) in order to overlap the bullet too (ex.: -20px).

```
ul li a {
    position: relative;
    left: -20px;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid the link is not possible without changing the html or adding JS. A possible work around to use a `list-style-type: none;` and add a `div` to the `li` with a background (in your case background-image).
Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/SBwUT/

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#"><div></div></a>link</li>
    <li><a href="#"><div></div></a>link</li>
    <li><a href="#"><div></div></a>link</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
div {
    float: left;
    background: red;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

Comment: `<li>` bullets are inherently unclickable as they're not actually elements. Using an `<a>` is the best way to do this, especially when an image is needed, so +1. I'm not sure why you need the inner `<div>` though?

Comment: It seemed more natural to set the background to the div, might not be necessary...

Comment: I'd just set the background on the `<a>` and move all the styles to it too, but it's personal preference I suppose

Comment: This way does work but it is not necessary to have the extra divs because you can style the li items with padding. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Not sure what you're actually trying to accomplish, as you cannot add a link to the background bullet image.

Comment: Update your main post, don't add it in the comments :)